# Iterated projecta and their respective iterated Skolem functions

Tags: set-theory

So I have been trying to study some fine structure from M. Zeman and R. Schindler's article in the handbook, and I have run into a few questions regarding the iterated Skolem functions for iterated projecta.

My first question might seem a little bit nitpicky, but it actually plays a considerable role in my misunderstandings. So here it goes: $\bf{(I)}$ on page $633$, above lemma $5.4$ the functions $h^{n+1}_M$ are defined. And the domain of each $h^{n+1}_M$ is $$\omega^{<\omega} \times |M^{n+1,p}|^{<\omega},$$ and we also have that $\mbox{On}\cap M^{n+1,p} = \rho_{n+1}(M)$. On the other hand, in lemma $5.4$, it is claimed that $$M = h^{n+1}_M"(\rho_{n+1}(M)\cup \{p\}),$$ for some $p\in R^{n+1}_M$. But then $p$ is a finite seq. of finite seq.s of ordinals above $\rho_{n+1}(M)$ and so is not in the domain of $h^{n+1}_M$!

Am I right? Or am I missing something? As a note I can say that I do understand the recursive phenomenon described a few lines above this definition, but there, we can't feed $p$ directly to each $h$ function and we break it up to each individual $p(i)$ and use it at the $i$-th step, but I don't see how we can do it formally with the given definition.

My next $2$ questions involve lemma $5.5$:

$\bf{(II)}$ The statement of lemma $5.5$ is odd. Meaning that I think if we take $M = (J_\alpha^B, D)$, an acceptable $J$-structure, then this lemma seems to imply that if $R^n_M \neq \emptyset$, then $\rho_0(M) = \rho_1(M) = \dots = \rho_n(M) = \alpha$. Meaning that $M$ is actually very rigid up to $n$, which seems in some sense very counter-intuitive, because then the only possibility for $p \in R^n_M$ is for it to be $p = \emptyset$, which seems odd. To see the above fact we show it for $\rho_1(M)$ and for $m\le n$, the result follows by iterating the proof for case $m =1$ by induction. Now if $\rho_1(M) < \alpha$, let $T \in {\bf \Sigma}_1^M\cap P(\rho_1(M))$ such that $T \not\in M$. But since $T \in {\bf \Sigma}_1^M \subset {\bf \Sigma}_\omega^{M^{1, p|1}}$, by $5.5$, and since $P(J_{\rho_1(M)})\cap \mbox{rud}_{B, A^{1,p|1}_M}(J_{\rho_1(M)}\cup\{J_{\rho_1(M)}\}) = P(J_{\rho_1(M)}) \cap {\bf \Sigma}_\omega^{M^{1, p|1}}$, then $T\in M$ by the fact that $\rho_1 < \alpha$ and so $\mbox{rud}_{B, A^{1,p|1}_M}(J_{\rho_1(M)}\cup\{J_{\rho_1(M)}\}) \subset M$. Which is a contradiction by the choice of $T$. So $\rho_1(M) = \alpha$.

Is my above reasoning correct? If not, I would appreciate it if someone would kindly point out my mistake.

$\bf{(III)}$ I also have trouble with the proof of lemma $5.5$. The main one is the last equivalence in the proof. My main concern is that when using $h^n_M$, I don't know how we handle the $p\in R^n_M$ as a parameter to generate the members we want, and also the abuse of notation of writing $h^n_M$ with only one input rather than the tuple it needs, makes the proof hard for me to understand. Can someone kindly elaborate more on the details of this proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the definition of $h^{n+1}_M$ is slightly inaccurate in this article. I will write $h^{n+1, p}_M$ to make the dependence on the parameter $p$ clear. $p$ should be fed into the iterated $\Sigma_1$-Skolem functions at the apropriate places: Instead of
$$h^{n+1}_M(\langle\vec i, i_0,\dots i_k\rangle, \langle \vec x_{i_0},\dots, \vec x_{i_k}\rangle) $$
$$=h^n_M(\vec i, \langle h_{M^{n, p\upharpoonright n}}(i_0, \vec x_{i_0}),\dots, h_{M^{n, p\upharpoonright n}}(i_k, \vec x_{i_k})\rangle)$$
it should be
$$h^{n+1, p}_M(\langle\vec i, i_0,\dots i_k\rangle, \langle \vec x_{i_0},\dots, \vec x_{i_k}\rangle) $$
$$=h^{n, p\upharpoonright n}_M(\vec i, \langle h_{M^{n, p\upharpoonright n}}(i_0, \vec x_{i_0}^\frown p(n)),\dots, h_{M^{n, p\upharpoonright n}}(i_k, \vec x_{i_k}^\frown p(n))\rangle)$$

(with $h^{0, \emptyset}_M=h_M$). Both authors published books in which the function $h^{n, p}_M$ is, modulo some technicalities, defined in this way (Ralf Schindler's  "Set Theory" p.252 and Martin Zeman's "Inner Modles and Large Cardinals" p.29, note that the function is called $\tilde h^{n}_M$ in the latter).

One can also think of $p$ as an additional argument of the function $h^n_M$, i.e. $h^n_M(\vec i, \vec x, p)=h^{n, p}_M(\vec i, \vec x)$. This is in fact a feature of $\tilde h^n_M$ in Zeman's book. This also explains
$$M=h^{n+1}_M"(\rho_{n+1}(M)\cup\{p\})$$
by slight abuse of notation.

Regarding $\mathbf{(II)}$: It is definately possible that $R^n_M\neq\emptyset$ and $\rho_n(M)< \alpha$. For example, all levels of the $J$-hierachy are acceptable and sound so that $R^n_{J_\alpha}=P^n_{J_\alpha}\neq\emptyset$ for all $n$ and there are plenty of $\alpha$ for which $\rho_1(J_\alpha)<\alpha$.

The problem in your argument is that
$$\mathrm{rud}_{B, A^{1, p\upharpoonright 1}_M}(J^B_{\rho_1(M)}\cup\{J^B_{\rho_1(M)}\})\subseteq M$$
cannot be justified. This is true if the additional $A^{1, p\upharpoonright 1}_M$ is dropped from the subscript of $\mathrm{rud}$, but more cannot be said. Note that $A^{1, p\upharpoonright 1}_M\notin M$ but is an element of the rudimentary closure on the left hand side!

On $\mathbf{(III)}$, I believe the fog should settle when every instance of $h^n_M(z')$ in the proof of Lemma 5.5 is replaced by $h^{n, p}_M(z')$ with the definition from above. That this works is a consequence of $M=h^{n, p}_M"M^{n, p}$.

Comment: Oh, the proof of the lemma is clear now. Thanks!